# EF Core LINQ query comparing string to float

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a DB first project against SQL Server using EF Core 6 and unfortunately a column on one side of a join is float and on other it's a string.  Trying to compare the two in a where clause like

```
.Where(
  ea => ea.DoubleField == Convert.ToDouble(udc.StringField.Trim())
)
```

Works as long as the string field can be converted. But unfortunately this DB model can store non floats in that column for whatever reason. eg "A".

I tried to early exit the and condition with

```
.Where(
  ea =>  EF.Functions.IsNumeric(udc.StringField.Trim()) && ea.DoubleField == Convert.ToDouble(udc.StringField.Trim())
)
```

but that fails the same way (SQL Server must not care for early exit ands)

Also tried comparing as strings

```
.Where(
  ea =>  ea.DoubleField.ToString()  == udc.StringField.Trim()
)
```

This doesn't fail but doesn't work because the SQL provider is making `ToString()` just `convert(varchar(100), DoubleField)` which comes out as scientific notation and the comparison does not evaluate to true since one side is scientific notation.

What's the right way to compare a string to dobule safely in EF Core?

Comment: Don't compare strings to floats. That's a critical bug. If you want to store numbers, use the correct type. Indexes apply to the original stored values so your attempt to compare strings and numbers will have to scan the entire table

Comment: Mixing different types of data in the same field is another, fundamental bug. Fields contain one value, of one specific type. That's probably the most fundamental design rule. Break it and you're essentially dealing with flat files, not databases

Comment: It's the same in C# too - ORMs like EF deal with *entities*, not tables. Why does your application entity have a field acts both as a string and number? You wouldn't store `42` in the `Person.Name` property after all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's db first, i can't change it.  you can go tell the JD Edwards devs your beliefs, but it's irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: ....Where(x => double.TryParse(udc.StringField, out double doubledString) ? doubledString == ea.DoubleField : false); may be that will help.

Comment: @ChrisDaMour have you tried converting the double to a string and comparing the strings, rather than converting the string to a double to compare doubles? That'd avoid your issue where the udc.StringField can't parse as a double. It's not ideal as you're no longer comparing actual numbers and you might have floating point issues, but might have more success.

Comment: @kayndarr yes that was the last thing i showed an example of and i explain why that did not work

Comment: @spzvtbg you can't have out vars in an expression tree so TryParse doesn't work for linq expressions

Comment: @ChrisDaMour Are you able to maybe provide a formatting option in the ToString() call, e.g. ToString("#.##"), to get around the scientific notation problem?

Comment: @Kayndarr i did try that, but doesn't seem to be supported by ef core sql provider, at least all the formats i tried.    it's not listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

Comment: ... right no outs in expressions. Can't you try parsing the string outside the Linq,

Comment: @ChrisDaMour on the contrary, it's 100% relevant. And I had to fix or recover from quite a few bad ERP database designs. You have to change what you're doing, or this won't work. And since it's an ERP, a full table scan on a huge table will block users and cause huge problems for customers. That's enough reason to cancel big projects.

Comment: @ChrisDaMour Are you sure you're joining on the correct fields? Just because an account field seems to be a number doesn't seem it is. Or that it's meant to be the key you're meant to use. Quite often, such unfortunate JOINs are created by third-party consultants or implementors that didn't want to go through the complex network of tables needed to go from one piece of information to the next. In other cases, it's a bad decision to use eg custom fields to store extra document types or info. The specifics matter

Comment: @ChrisDaMour finally, why are you JOINing at all? It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from the relations between entities. EF deals with entities not tables. If you want `OrderItem.Custom_Field_1` to link to an `Airlines` table, the correct way is to add a relation between your `OrderItem` entity and the `Airline` entity, not JOIN all over the application. You'd still have to somehow match the field types but the rest of the application wouldn't know. You may be able to use eager vs lazy vs explicit loading to eg load `OrderItem` instances and then fill them with `Airline` from a lookup cache

Comment: @ChrisDaMour finally, ERPs may have hierarchical IDs like `15.1` or `15.1.45` or `A.15.B12`, especially when it comes to accounts and subaccounts. These aren't decimals *at all*, even if they seem so if the data is limited. Matching these is a completely different problem because you can't use simple string comparisons or range searches. `15.1` and `15.01` may refer to the same account, but string comparisons would miss them

Comment: @ChrisDaMour so how would you describe your problem to another ERP developer?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i don't want to argue with you on this stuff, i can't change the db. sql server can leverage indexes on conversion (unlike oracle) so not a concern on the performance.  i'm joining because i need to and i'm certain this is how it has to be, as you can see form my example i'm letting the orm figure out the sql, it's just a join (really an outer apply) that it's coming up with so i used that term.  you're very draining....

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged SQL server when it's not a SQL solution you are looking for.

Comment: @DaleK what do you mean? the db EF core is querying is SQL Server using the SQL Server Provider. seems like it's very much SQL Server related

Comment: You're not looking for an SQL Server expert, you're looking for a LINQ expert.

Comment: @DaleK ok i didn't realize that's how the tags worked, thought since this is EF Core against SQL Server i should tag it that way...the solution may very well be in SQL but it can be removed

Comment: Is it a performance issue if you do this in C# after an `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: This is an EF Core and SQL Server problem, not a LINQ problem. SQL Server's provider has better conversions that Oracle's BUT CONVERSIONS AREN'T INDEXED. So you *do* get full table scans and a huge performance hit. To avoid it, you'd need an indexed computed column

Comment: You need to explain the actual problem, the same way you'd explain it to an ERP developer. ORMs don't do JOINs so just talking about JOINs isn't "just". Parsing is available, but parsing the `Convert.ToDouble` or `double.Parse` is up to the EF provider. Even then, `double.Parse` et al are locale-aware so you need to specify the correct CultureInfo. You'd need to find an expression that translates to `TRY_CONVERT()` or `TRY_CAST()` at least. To avoid localization issues you'd need `TRY_PARSE(... USING 'en-us')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos- fwiw sql provider doesn't understand the double.Parse per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to restructure my linq like so leveraging the fact that ? : become t-sql case statements

```
.Where(
  ea =>  ea.DoubleField == EF.Functions.IsNumeric(udc.StringField.Trim()) ?   Convert.ToDouble(udc.StringField.Trim()) : -1
)
```

does rely on assumption of -1 not matching any value in DoubleField

for the curious this is transpiled into this t-sql

```
([f2].[DoubleField] = CASE
                  WHEN ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM([f1].[StringField]))) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, LTRIM(RTRIM([f1].[StringField])))
                  ELSE -1.0E0
              END))
```

despite what was repeated in the comments of my question many times, the explain plan shows this using indexes and no full table scans.

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION that i did NOT attempt but looks viable, where i could leverage a TRY_CONVERT as mentioned in comment and map that from my linq using a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-method-to-a-custom-sql but that syntax is pretty gnarly and i wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Just discovered that there is no equivalent method for `decimal` because `ISNUMERIC` will return true for scientific notation (e.g. `1234E+15`), but the conversion to decimal will fail.